# Svelte shows host directory structure on 404

Tags: http-status-code-404, svelte, sveltekit, custom-error-pages

When I access a non-existing path in my Svelte app I, expectedly, get a 404:

> 404
> Not found: /fsadfsdaf
> Error: Not found: /fsadfsdaf
> at resolve (file:///home/myuser/some/path/on/the/host/build/server/index.js:2481:20)
> at Object.options.hooks.handle (file:///home/myuser/some/path/on/the/host/build/server/index.js:2746:69)
> at respond (file:///home/myuser/some/path/on/the/host/build/server/index.js:2396:42)

The problem is that this leaks the directory structure on the host, which is something I'd very gladly keep private.

This is an app built with the usual `vite build` command, I'm not serving a production build.

How do I prevent the directory structure from being shown to anyone who types a gibberish URL? Is the simplest way to make my own `+error` page or is there anything simpler, considering I don't want anything specific to be shown on the page?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the SvelteKit documentation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#error), SvelteKit will look for a `+error.svelte` file in the corresponding directory, and will keep walking up the directory tree until it finds an `+error.svelte` file. Failing to find any of these files will cause SvelteKit to

> bail out and render a static fallback error page, which you can customise by creating a `src/error.html` file

Failing to find that static fallback page will cause SvelteKit to render a default error page, which in non-production builds will likely include a stacktrace (which is what you're seeing).

Adding a static `src/error.html` file will likely solve your problem, considering you do not wish to show anything specific on that error page.

Alternatively, if you wished to display a little more information (such as a status code like 404, 500, etc.) to differentiate error causes, you could add a `src/routes/+error.svelte` file to handle errors throughout your routing tree.

Comment: But that implies that my build is not a production one, despite it being built with `yarn build --mode production`. I solved my issue by including a barebones `+error.svelte` page but I wouldn't expect a stack trace to be visible on a production build.